# Integration of exponential function with complex number

Tags: integration

I have a problem such as;

$$ \frac{\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}\ e^{ajx} dx} {\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}\ e^{bjx} dx} $$

Where a and b just constants, and j is complex number (sqrt(-1)) Is there any way to simplify this equation.
Thank you...

Comment: What is $j$ here?

Comment: It is complex number, sqrt(-1)

Comment: Thanks for edit advices

Comment: These integrals never converge, unless the world changed during my hibernation.

Comment: Maybe someone more knowledgeable than me about the Dirac delta function might know if there is any connection here? I feel like there would be a way to simplify using Dirac delta but I don't know how to do so rigorously.

Comment: @csch2 Actually I end up with this while doing calculations with the Dirac Delta function. My purpose is to find a correlation between two different Dirac functions

Answer (score 3):

$$\int_{-p}^{+p}\ e^{iax} \,dx=\frac{2 \sin (a p)}{a}$$
$$\frac{\int_{-p}^{+p}\ e^{iax} \,dx } {\int_{-p}^{+p}\ e^{ibx} \,dx }=\frac b a \frac {\sin (a p)}{\sin (b p)}$$ and now, we face a problem when $p\to \infty$.